# moment.js - change format of already formatted past date

Tags: javascript, date, formatting, momentjs

I need to get a past date with moment.js (http://momentjs.com/) which I receive in specific format:

```
moment('31.10.2013', 'dd.mm.yy');
```

That returns me a strange response where I see a current date in `_d` option:

```
// returns
_a: Array[7]
_d: Wed Nov 06 2013 00:10:00 GMT+0200 (EET)
_f: "dd.mm.yy"
_i: "26.10.2013"
_isUTC: false
_l: undefined
_pf: Object
_strict: undefined
```

I assume that is the problem when I do formatting:

```
moment('31.10.2013', 'dd.mm.yy').format('YYYY/MM/DD');
// returns current date (why??!)
// "2013/11/06"
```

So what is wrong here, could I format the past date?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

At first I thought it was the format, but it was actually the format in, lower case means something different than uppercase both in and out.

```
moment('31.10.2013', 'DD.MM.YYYY').format('YYYY/MM/DD')
>> "2013/10/31"

moment('31.10.2013', 'dd.mm.yyyy').format('YYYY/MM/DD')
>> "2013/11/06"
```

So fix your input mask, not the format.